# Grab a vertex under mouse position in GLScene

Tags: delphi, opengl, vertex, glscene

I'm writing a 3D modeling application using GLScene , so I need to move some vertices under mouse position to new position by grabbing the vertex.
First of all, I load a sphere and pick up a vertex by mouse,then I try to drag it but I realize that the vertex doesn't move under mouse caret correctly.

[image: My application]

```
    unit Unit1;

    interface

    uses
      Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
      Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Math,
      //GLScene
      GLWin32Viewer, GLCrossPlatform, GLBaseClasses, GLScene, GLColor, GLCanvas,
      GLVectorFileObjects, GLObjects,GLVectorTypes,
      GLCoordinates, GLFileObj, GLVectorGeometry;

    type
      TForm1 = class(TForm)
        GLSceneViewer: TGLSceneViewer;
        GLScene1: TGLScene;
        GLLightSource1: TGLLightSource;
        GLCamera: TGLCamera;
        GLDummyCube1: TGLDummyCube;
        FreeForm: TGLFreeForm;
        GLLightSource2: TGLLightSource;
        procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
        procedure GLSceneViewerMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
        procedure GLSceneViewerMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
        procedure GLSceneViewerMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
        procedure GLSceneViewerPostRender(Sender: TObject);
      private
        { Private declarations }
        IsVertexDragging: Boolean;

        MouseX, MouseY : Integer;
        VertexIndexToDrag: Integer;
        CenterPosition, LastPosition: TVector3f;
        function FindClosestPointIndex(Point: TVector3f): Integer;

      public
        { Public declarations }
      end;

    var
      Form1: TForm1;

    implementation

    {$R *.dfm}

    procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      FreeForm.LoadFromFile('E:\test2\Sphere.obj');
    end;

    function TForm1.FindClosestPointIndex( Point: TVector3f ): Integer;
    var
      i: Integer;
      NewPoint : TVector3f;
      BestDistance,
      TempDistance: Single;
    begin
      // Search the nearest point between  all vertices in the sphere.
      BestDistance := 100000000000000;
      for i:=0 to FreeForm.MeshObjects[0].Vertices.Count-1 do
      begin

          NewPoint := FreeForm.MeshObjects[0].Vertices[i];
          TempDistance := VectorDistance( Point, NewPoint );

          if TempDistance <= BestDistance  then
          begin
            BestDistance := TempDistance;
            Result := i;
          end;
      end;

    end;

    procedure TForm1.GLSceneViewerMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    var
      Vertex: TVector3f;
    begin

      MouseX := X;
      MouseY := Y;

      if (ssLeft in Shift) and not (ssCtrl in Shift) then
      begin
        IsVertexDragging := True;

        Vertex := GLSceneViewer.Buffer.PixelRayToWorld( X, Y );
        Vertex := FreeForm.AbsoluteToLocal(Vertex);

        // Find closest point to the mouse click position
        VertexIndexToDrag := FindClosestPointIndex( Vertex );
        //start of dragging position.
        CenterPosition := GLSceneViewer.Buffer.ScreenToWorld(X,Y);

      end;
    end;

    procedure TForm1.GLSceneViewerMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    var
      delta: TVector3f;
      i: Integer;
    begin
      if (ssLeft in Shift) and (ssCtrl in Shift) then // Rotating camera
        GLCamera.MoveAroundTarget(0.5*(MouseY-Y), 0.5*(MouseX-X) )
      else
      if (ssLeft in Shift) and not (ssCtrl in Shift) and IsVertexDragging then
      begin // Dragging vertex

        LastPosition := GLSceneViewer.Buffer.ScreenToWorld(X,Y);

        delta.X := RoundTo( LastPosition.X - CenterPosition.X, -5 );
        delta.Y := RoundTo( LastPosition.Y - CenterPosition.Y, -5 );
        delta.Z := RoundTo( LastPosition.Z - CenterPosition.Z, -5 );

        Caption := delta.Z.ToString;
        CenterPosition := LastPosition;

        FreeForm.MeshObjects[0].Vertices.TranslateItem( VertexIndexToDrag , Delta );

        FreeForm.TransformationChanged;
      end;

      MouseX := X;
      MouseY := Y;

    end;

    procedure TForm1.GLSceneViewerMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    begin
      IsVertexDragging := False;
    end;

    procedure TForm1.GLSceneViewerPostRender(Sender: TObject);
    var
      glc: TGLCanvas;
    begin
      // Show a circle with mouse position
      if IsVertexDragging then
      begin
        glc := TGLCanvas.Create( GLSceneViewer.Width, GLSceneViewer.Height );
        glc.PenWidth := 2;
        glc.PenColor := clLime;
        glc.Ellipse( MouseX, MouseY, 5, 5 );
        glc.Free;
      end;
      GLSceneViewer.Invalidate;

    end;

    end.
```

what is my wrong? I want to write a tools like [stephaneginier.com/sculptgl](http://stephaneginier.com/sculptgl/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to think of this is solving the following [line-plane intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93plane_intersection):

[image]

The distance along ***l***, *d* can be found like so:

[image]

The intersection point is then

[image]

All you need now are the inputs. I've never used GLScene, so this is just to point you in the right direction:

- The normal `n` is the [camera's forward direction, `GLCamera.Direction`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137587/glscene-convert-3d-vector-into-current-camera-vector).
- The point on the plane, `p_0` is `LocalToAbsolute(Vertex)`
- The ray start, `l_0`, is either the camera's position, `GLCamera.Position` or a point on the near plane, `GLSceneViewer.Buffer.ScreenToWorld(x, y)`.
- The ray direction, `l`, is the projected mouse direction, `GLSceneViewer.Buffer.ScreenToVector(x, y)`

Finally, you'll want to put the intersection point back into object space with `AbsoluteToLocal`.

It looks like there may be shortcuts for this intersection test (e.g. using the ray from `PixelRayToWorld`), but like I said I don't know GLScene.

Comment: Would you please bring some sample GLScene code for doing this? Unfortunately I'm weak in mathematics .

Comment: @naserdaneshi I've searched a little. Hope it helps.